# std::string not being resolved in Eclipse/CDT 8.0

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

Seemed to have worked fine in CDT 7.0 in Eclipse Helios, but since upgrading I'm getting a lot of unresolved symbols in my C++ projects, namely a lot of STL classes.

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio toolchain or something like Cygwin?

Comment: Same here. Using the latest MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem with CDT 8, but then they got automatically resolved and now it all works perfectly. I think holding a cursor above the `#includes` and `using` directives tells eclipse to scan those namespaces and includes and to stop showing those errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is an indexer option "Index source and header files opened in editor" and it seems to be deactivated by default. By activating it, I got rid of "all unresolved when opening a file" and "staying unresolved after building".